# Can't get my function to work mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile

On my wordpress page I use this function:

```
if (jQuery(window).width() < 960) {jQuery(".nav li a").click(function (){ jQuery("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");}});
```

but it just don't work on mobile. Can someone give me a hint what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing closing parenthesis:

```
if (jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
  jQuery(".nav li a").click(function () { 
      jQuery("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  }); // the parenthesis here was missing
}
```

If your syntax is correct on your live site and that was just a typo in your question, share a link to the live site.

Also for WordPress, it's best to wrap everything in a block like this due to its no-conflict mode, you're free to use the `$` shorthand inside this block:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $(".nav li a").click(function () { 
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    }); // the parenthesis here was missing
  }

});
```

Comment: thanks it was my document ready function which had something missing!